# From LaTeX to BBCode and back

Tags: regex, latex, sublimetext2, bbcode, tex

I wasn't able to recover a similar thread, but I'm surprised nobody asked something so elementary before.

I would like to convert a couple of (quite long, so long I don't want to do it manually) LaTeX notes into something I can post in a forum which supports TeX code between the [tex]...[/tex] BBCode delimiters.

Hence I would like to find an automated way to replace, say,

`$e^{i\pi}$`

with

`[tex]e^{i\pi}[/tex]`

and vice versa (easier); possibly something I can write once and for all and execute each time I need it. The best of all would be a solution which also converts \section{...}, \subsection{...} and other environments, but this isn't mandatory, since the only issue with these documents is that they contain tons of math.

My impression is that a professional tool like, say, PanDoc, is too much a "nuke the fly" approach (not to mention I'm not able to use it)... I'm able to use a couple of features of the sublime-text editor, so it would be wonderful if you want to help me referring to it. In any case, keep in mind that I feel kinda yahoo about regex-stuff and suchlike (I've always seen them like a sorcery, or better, I was too dumb to learn them), so please be verbose. :)

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX is a Turing-complete programming language, so a simple regex won't do what you want in general.  That said, [Andrew Stacey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315213/andrew-stacey) specializes in compiling LaTeX code to various formats, e.g. [today's post on G+](https://plus.google.com/110765980098077923527/posts/HWnZmXybW3y).  I bet he has a program that would parse your latex and emit bbcode.